# Application Forcefully closed on run.

Tags: android, onclicklistener

When I tried to run the code it says , the application has stopped unfortunately .Please help me with my coding . Below is the code for which I want the solution .

```
package gaurav.android;

import java.util.*;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;

public class EventActivity extends Activity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    View colorregion;
    int[] colorchoices = {Color.BLACK , Color.BLUE, Color.CYAN};
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        colorregion = findViewById(R.id.color_region);
        Button clbutton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.color_button);
        clbutton.setOnClickListener((OnClickListener) new ColorRandomizer());
    }
    private void regioncolor(int color)
    {
        colorregion.setBackgroundColor(color);
    }
    private class ColorRandomizer implements onClickListener
    {
        public void onClick(View v)
        {
            Random r= new Random();
            int index= r.nextInt(colorchoices.length);
            regioncolor(colorchoices[index]);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: main.xml and log cat please........

Comment: you should debug your code first before asking

Comment: paste your logcat to show what kind of error you get

Answer (score 1):

**Change your code**

```
private class ColorRandomizer implements onClickListener
    {
        public void onClick(View v)
        {
            Random r= new Random();
            int index= r.nextInt(colorchoices.length);
            regioncolor(colorchoices[index]);
        }
    }
```

**to this**

```
private class ColorRandomizer implements OnClickListener {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Random r = new Random();
            int index = r.nextInt(colorchoices.length);
            regioncolor(colorchoices[index]);
        }
    }
```

its not `onClickListener`
its **OnClickListener**

Comment: I am also having problem with these two lines

Comment: colorregion = findViewById(R.id.color_region);
Button clbutton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.color_button);

Comment: View (the type of colorregion)

Comment: i mean R.id.color_region is which control

Comment: Please verify that gaurav.android.R; is accessible or not

Answer (score 0):

```
    package com.test;

    import java.util.Random;

    import android.app.Activity;
    import android.graphics.Color;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
    import android.widget.Button;

    public class EventActivity extends Activity 
    {
     /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    View colorregion;
    int[] colorchoices = {Color.BLACK , Color.BLUE, Color.CYAN};
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        colorregion = findViewById(R.id.color_region);
        Button clbutton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.color_button);
        clbutton.setOnClickListener(new ColorRandomizer());
    }
    private void regioncolor(int color)
    {
        colorregion.setBackgroundColor(color);
    }
    private class ColorRandomizer implements OnClickListener
    {
        public void onClick(View v)
        {
            Random r= new Random();
            int index= r.nextInt(colorchoices.length);
            regioncolor(colorchoices[index]);
        }
    }

}
```